Image Previews Not Showing on Ubuntu Desktop
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 on my Dell XPS laptop. I am experiencing an issue where image previews (thumbnails) are not displayed on my desktop. Instead I see generic icons for image files:

Steps taken to troubleshoot:

Checked File Manager Settings:

I opened Files (Nautilus) and navigated to Preferences.
Under the Performance tab, I confirmed that the option to show thumbnails is set to All files.



I would appreciate any assistance in troubleshooting this issue further. Are there additional steps I might have missed, or is this a known issue with a specific fix?

This is very weird. If this is a bug then I am experiencing it too. The thumbnail shows in every folder except desktop.

This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 24.10.

Add "GSK_RENDERER=gl" to /etc/environment file
Run rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
Either restart or execute sudo systemctl restart gdm.service


It worked, thanks!
